# How to print out the positions of spaces and new lines?

Tags: c

I am trying to print out the position of the spaces and new lines from a text written in a file but its printing nothing and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

This is just part of the problem so please ignore the other defined stuff that I have not used yet.

Text file:

```
Mi illumino di immenso
Illumino di immenso
Di immenso
IMMENSO
```

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 100
int main()
{
    FILE *file,*file2;
    file=fopen("file","r");

    if(file==NULL || file2==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,p=0;
    int v[50];
    char str[N];
    int iteration=0;
    char str1[N];

    while(fscanf(file,"%s",str)!=EOF)
    {

        for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if(str[i]==' ')
            {
                v[j]=i;
                j++;

            }
            if(str[i]=='/n')
            {
                v[j]=i;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",v[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing is that `file2` is never initialized, but you're testing its value, which is junk. Another is that `fscanf` with a `%s` format specified is not doing what you think it is. Go read its documentation.  Also check out `fgets()` while you're there.

Comment: '/n' is malformed. Should be '\n'.

Comment: `fscanf(..., "%s", ...)` reads white space separated words.  What should the output be for the 2nd line?   If you read a line at at a time with `fgets()` your algorithm would reset the `i` for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `fscanf(..., "%s", str)` reads white separated words so `str` will never contain space or newline. You can use `%[^\n]\n` to read string with space but `str` won't contain the newline.  You could also use `%[a-zA-Z \n]` to specify what you want.
2. `\n' should be '/n'.
3. If you use `fgets()` instead of `fscanf()` you will reset `i` per line.  It's not clear if that that is what you want.
4. `str[N]` but `v[50]` yet worst case is a `str` that consist of all space and/or newline so it should be `v[N]`.
5. In the last loop you don't use any field separators.
6. You space and newline does the same thing so combining those two `if` conditions.
7. Eliminate unused variables (`file2`, `k`, `p`).
8. Close file.
9. Code is hard to read due to formatting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("file", "r");
    if(!file) {
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }

    char str[N];
    int j=0;
    int v[N];
    for(;;) {
        char *rv = fgets(str, N, file);
        if(!rv)
            break;
        size_t str_len = strlen(str);
        for(int i=0; i < str_len; i++) {
            if(str[i]==' ' || str[i] == '\n')
                v[j++] = i;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<j; i++) {
        printf("%d ",v[i]);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

and example output:

```
2 11 14 22 8 11 19 2 10 7
```

Comment: I have been under the impression that fscanf(...,"%s",...); read the whole line whitespaces and all until \n. What a time to understand it reads it word by word. Thanks for the code

Comment: You can use `fscanf()` to read a line with `%[^\n]` but it would not give you the newline, or use `%[a-zA-Z \n]` to specify what you want.  If you strings, however, you should always specify a maximum field width to prevent buffer overflows but to do requires a a couple of macros and you need a macro that contains `N-1` and `str[N]` which usually is with `#define N 99` and `str[N+1]`.  `fgets()` is just an easier interface to use in practice.